# C language: regexec returns not matching even the string matches the pattern

Tags: c, regex, posix

I use regex in the C language. I have the following code:

```
#include <regex.h>

static char input[] = "00001415_AXI_7_16";

static bool checkSn(char *input)
{
    regex_t regex;

    if (regcomp(&regex, "^\\d{1,8}_[A-Z]{3}_(\\*|\\d{1,3})_(\\*|\\d{1,3})$",
    REG_EXTENDED))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during creating regex\n");
        return false;
    }
    if (regexec(&regex, input, 0, NULL, 0))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I can compile the program without any warning. I can run the program, but the function returns false even the input string matches the regular expression, I tried it obviously at an online regular expression tester. Could you please help me where is a mistake?
Thank you in advance.

I tried few flags for the regcomp function. I tried the regular expression without "^" and without "$" with the same result.

Comment: POSIX extended regular expressions don't include things like `\d`. Use `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compile with `REG_EXTENDED` flag. However, the current regular expression using is the basic regular expression syntax.

You can change the regular expression to use the extended syntax, or you can remove the `REG_EXTENDED` flag from the regcomp function call.

With extended version:

```
if (regcomp(&regex, "^[[:digit:]]{1,8}_[[:upper:]]{3}_(\\*|[[:digit:]]{1,3})_(\\*|[[:digit:]]{1,3})$",
REG_EXTENDED))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error during creating regex\n");
    return false;
}
```

Or without:

```
if (regcomp(&regex, "^[0-9]\\{1,8\\}_[A-Z]\\{3\\}_\\(\\*\\|[0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)_\\(\\*\\|[0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)$",
0))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error during creating regex\n");
    return false;
}
```